# Populating a suppression list in Marketing Cloud From Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, suppressionlist

**Use Case**

The marketers in our organisation would like **to be able to add Salesforce contacts to a Marketing Cloud suppression list** in order to avoid emails being sent to them.

**Context**

The emails are being sent by a Journey that collects data from a Data extension that is populated by a Marketing Cloud Automation + API integration.

The *contacts* in the Marketing Cloud data extension are but a mirror of the Sales Cloud since the are both being synced by a similar process, so we can assume they are aligned.

So, at the end of the day, what would be the best approach for this? Checkbox + trigger? Any custom configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get 'Auto Suppression Lists' enabled on your account on the Parent Business Unit.

Create an Auto Suppression list from Admin > Auto Suppression Lists. An ASL can be applied to various business units and/or send classifications.

Automate a query to get from SF your suppressed account (flag, status etc). Include the required fields needed for the Auto Suppression list (Date Added, Email Address)

Add the results to a data extension.

Include in your automation a file extract to extract the records from your DE to CSV and upload to Safehouse

Also include a step in your automation to then import from Safehouse the CSV file and Import into the Auto Suppression List.

The auto Suppression list works at Email Address level (not subscriber key) and is applied on every send (based in send classifications and business units).

If a contact appears in a data extension or list and has been added to the auto Suppression list then they will be automatically suppressed. You therefore don't need to manually add the suppression list to each send